# Angularjs Nested states: 3 level

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ionic-framework

I am using Agnularjs and Ionic Framework. I am trying to achieve a nested states, which looks like below,

- Eventmenu(root)
- Home (2 level)
- Home 1 (3 level)
- Home 2
- checkin
- attendee

My routes file looks like,

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('eventmenu', {
      url: "/event",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "event-menu.html"
    })
    .state('eventmenu.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "home.html"
        }
      }
    })
      .state('eventmenu.home.home1', {
      url: "/home1",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "home1.html"
        }
      }
    })
        .state('eventmenu.home.home2', {
      url: "/home2",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "home2.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.checkin', {
      url: "/check-in",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "check-in.html",
          controller: "CheckinCtrl"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.attendees', {
      url: "/attendees",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "attendees.html",
          controller: "AttendeesCtrl"
        }
      }
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event/home");
})
```

For full example, please see codepen: http://codepen.io/liamqma/pen/mtBne

```
/event/home
/event/checkin
```

are working, but

```
/event/home/home1
/event/home/home2
```

are not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wheres the ionic part? This looks like a normal angularJS app no Ionic directives anywhere...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I solved your problem there : http://codepen.io/yrezgui/pen/mycxB

Basically, Ionic is using Angular-UI-Router which has a huge API. In your case, you need to check this link to understand : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names

To be short, home1 and home2 states are children of home state, so they can't have access of menuContent view, because it's related to eventmenu state.

So you need to write :

```
.state('eventmenu.home.home2', {
  url: "/home2",
  views: {
    'menuContent@eventmenu' :{
      templateUrl: "home2.html"
    }
  }
})
```

Instead of :

```
.state('eventmenu.home.home2', {
  url: "/home2",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "home2.html"
    }
  }
})
```

And home1 wasn't working even after this modification because its url was :

```
url: "/home/home1",
```

Instead of :

```
url: "/home1",
```

By writing *eventmenu.home.home1*, you make **home1** a child of **home**, so its url needs to be relative, not absolute.

Hope you understand it and have fun with Ionic ;)

Comment: problem is you don't get sweet ionic page transitions :'( great post nonetheless @Yacine

Comment: What if eventmenu.home state was an abstract layer too, like eventmenu is?

Comment: @MarcelFalliere did you manage to have a good transition effect with your case? I tried everything, to create abstract layer for level 2 page with separate ion-nav-view, but the views are jumping... ?

Comment: Thank you. So in other words, add the parent with @ after view name.