# Ui router URL bug

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

It doesn't work with the last one where there are three states. How do I make it work?

There is no error. The page itself doesn't load (It`s like I press link and nothing changes (except url in browser address line) )

```
.state('parent', {
            url: '/home',
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view/>'
        })
        .state('parent.index', {
            url: '/index',
            template: '<h1>test1</h1>'
        })
        .state('parent.contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            template: '<h1>test2</h1>'
        })
        .state('parent.contact.test', {
            url: '/test',
            template: '<h1>test3</h1>'
        })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs Nested states: 3 level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818515/angularjs-nested-states-3-level)

Comment: please explain in detail. which error exactly you're facing? please make your question more elaborative.

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Try for this,
To be short, contact states are children of parentstate, so they can't have access of Test view, because it's related to test state.

So you need to write :

```
.state('parent.contact.test', {
  url: "/test",
  views: {
    'Test@test' :{
      templateUrl: "test.html"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried but it didnt work also:( Can you create a plunkr to show how it should be?